# datatype for count result in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Look at this piece of code:

```
public long my_function()
{
    return bdd.Database.SqlQuery<long>("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable")).First();
}
```

This code works great on a mysql database.

But if i run the same code on an sql server database, i get this error:

```
Erreur: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Int64' type is not valid.
```

I works if i change my code to:

```
public int my_function()
{
    return bdd.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable")).First();
}
```

In fact, i think that sql server use an int32 for count(*) return value and mysql is using an int64. EF and C# are not able to cast int32 to int64 (strange ?)

Did you notice this before ?

I am wondering what will happen if my count(*) exceed int32 capacity...
(a have a lot of records)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Did you notice this before ?

**Yes**

> I am wondering what will happen if my count(*) exceed int32
>   capacity... (a have a lot of records)

**An arithmetic overflow error**

Try this instead if you are concerned about the number of records you have:

```
public long my_function()
{
    return bdd.Database.SqlQuery<long>("SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) FROM mytable")).First();
}
```

Reference: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server `COUNT` returns a SQL INT which maps to `Int32` in .Net. If you need a larger value, you need to use [`COUNT_BIG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx)

From the docs:

> COUNT_BIG always returns a bigint data type value. COUNT always returns an int data type value.